# Pandas - ignoring formatted data types when reading csvs

Tags: python, pandas

I have a very simple function which is intended to parse and reformat a CSV file:

```
def parseFile(path, cols=[]):
    """
    Parse futures file given in path and re-index, only keep cols provided
    in cols.
    -------------------
    Usage:
        data = parseFileCSI('C:\\data\\66\\ad_9609', ['Open', 'Volume'])
    """

    filename = path.split('\\')[-1].split('.')[0]
    df = pd.read_csv(path, engine='c')
    df['ID'] = filename

    #align column names with TRTH
    df.rename(columns={'Fut Expiration Date':'ExpirationDate'}, inplace=True)

    df.set_index(['ID', 'ExpirationDate'], inplace=True)

    #keep specified columns
    if cols != []:
        df = df[cols]

    return df
```

However, in the csv files the expiration dates are reformatted to something I do not desire, which can be seen below:

[image: date]

I have thousands of these csv's that I read systematically, so it is not viable to go through and change all of them. How can I parse those date strings, f.e. `'01-Apr-96'`, and convert them to valid dates?

Comment: What format do you want?

Comment: What is your desired format of Expiration Date?

Comment: `%m/%d/%Y` is the ideal output... but converting all of those columns using to_datetime() to reformat is a very expensive operation.

Comment: But if it's not in the correct format in the underlying `.csv` file then you have to reformat it somehow. It won't magically just turn into what you want. `pd.to_datetime` is one option and I strongly recommend it because if you're going to do any calculations with dates, you probably want them to be `datetime` anyway.

Comment: Yes, but in the csv the raw value in the cell is in the format I desire, however it is reformatted using some excel option (visible in the image). I was wondering if there was some way to get the underlying data as opposed to the formatted data; if it is not possible then I guess it isn't.

Comment: Your problem isn't a pandas/python problem, but an Excel 'feature'. As you can see in the formule-bar in your excel-screenshot (and as you say, also in your csv), the dates are in the desired format (mm/dd/yyyy). But the (standard) Excel-format on your system is diferent. In Excel, just select the colomn, and change the data-format to 'mm/dd/yyyy'. You can probably also set this as the standard format if you want Excel to open all your files in this exact format.

Comment: In Windows, you can change the standard date-format in your configuration settings. Excel will by default use this format for dates, unles you change it manually with cell format. .

Comment: Open the CSV with any plain text editor/viewer (e.g. Notepad) and you will be able to see the file as it is. When you open the CSV with Excel, Excel will try to be helpful and detect/auto-format the data that it shows you.

Comment: I see... so as a followup question, how can I parse a date like `01-Apr-96` and change it to the time I want? It doesn't seem like Excel is letting me change a default preference without having to edit all of the files manually.

Comment: I know that every year that is larger than 80 should be 1980, 1981, etc, and anything under 80 should be 2001, 2002, etc. I'm not sure how to implement this logic in a vectorized manner.